# How do you count the list of strings VBA Excel?

Tags: vb.net, excel, vba

I'm still new to VBA Excel coding. Do tell me if there's anything that needs improvement.

In the example below I'm trying to get the list of even values from the generate class and insert into the excel vba sheet. But how do I count the number of list returned?

```
Private Function Generate()
    Dim red(1 To 20) As String
    For i = 1 To 20
        red(i) = i * 2
    Next i
    Generate = red()
End Function

Sub Format()
    Dim str() As String
    str() = Generate
    Range("A1").Select
    With Selection
        For i = 1 To str().Count               'what do I do with this? Obviously str().Count is not working.
           .Offset(1, i).Value = str(i)
        Next
    End With
End Sub
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Managed to solve on my own and here is the answer:

```
Private Function Generate()
    Dim red(1 To 20) As String
    For i = 1 To 20
        red(i) = i * 2
    Next i
    Generate = red()
End Function

Sub Format()
    Dim str() As String
    str() = Generate

    Range("A1").Select
    With Selection
        For i = LBound(str) To UBound(str)
           .Offset(i - 1, 0).Value = str(i)
        Next
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: You could still eliminate the `Range("A1").Select` line and use `for i = 1 to ubound(str)` then `Range("A" & i).Value = str(i)`. and if your array isn't a 1 based you change 1 to `lbound(str)`

Comment: Appreciated for suggestions.

Comment: You could declare red as a 2D array: `red(1 to 20, 1 to 1)`; assign the values to elements of the 1st Dimension `red(i,1) = i*2` ; then, in your Format macro, use just the single line (no loops or select): `Range("A1").Resize(ubound(str)) = str`